# Why does the complex equation $z=Ae^{it}+Be^{-it}$ represent an ellipse?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why does the complex equation $z=Ae^{it}+Be^{-it}$ represent an ellipse?, with $A,B \in \mathbb C$

How can it be described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take real and imaginary parts, with $A=a+bi$, $C=c+di$. Then the real and imaginary parts are
$$ \binom{(a+c)\cos{t}+(d-b)\sin{t}}{(b+d)\cos{t}+(a-c)\sin{t}} = \begin{pmatrix} a+c & d-b \\ b+d & a-c \end{pmatrix} \binom{\cos{t}}{\sin{t}} $$

---

**EDIT:** wow, this is only half-finished. The point is that if we take $x,y$ as the real and imaginary parts, then if we call the matrix $M$, then $(x,y) = M(\cos{t},\sin{t})$, so we can (partially) invert $M$ to get
$$ (\det{M})\binom{\cos{t}}{\sin{t}} = (\operatorname{adj}{M}) \binom{x}{y} $$
But then the norm is
$$ (\det{M})^2 = (\det{M})^2(\cos^2{t} + \sin^2{t}) = (x,y)^T (\operatorname{adj}{M})^T (\operatorname{adj}{M}) (x,y) ,$$
which is a sum of squares. (And this is true even if $M$ is not invertible.)

But it's easier to see directly: we get $\det{M} = a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$, so
$$ (a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2) \cos{t} = (a-c)x+(b-d)y \\
(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2) \sin{t} = -(b+d)x+(a+c)y $$
Now, if the determinant is zero, both of these give the same line. Otherwise, squaring and adding gives
$$ (a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2 = ((a-c)x+(b-d)y)^2 + (-(b+d)x+(a+c)y)^2 , $$
which is the formula for a conic section; it is an ellipse since it is written as the sum of two squares.

Even nicer is to start with the form $z = r e^{ip} e^{it} + s e^{iq} e^{-it}$: then we find that the equation of the quadratic form is
$$ 1 = (r^2-s^2)^{-2} \Big( (r^2+s^2+2rs\cos{(p+q)})x^2 +(- 2rs\sin{(p+q)})(2xy) + (r^2+s^2-2rs\cos{(p+q)})y^2 \Big) , $$
and it is straightforward to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, giving the canonical form
$$ 1 = \frac{1}{(r-s)^2} (x\cos{\tfrac{1}{2}(p+q)}+y\sin{\tfrac{1}{2}(p+q)})^2 + \frac{1}{(r+s)^2} (-x\sin{\tfrac{1}{2}(p+q)}+y\cos{\tfrac{1}{2}(p+q)})^2 $$

Comment: Wow, do you know a page or something which gives a more detailed explanation? because i cant see how the eigenvalues get in

Comment: This is (obviously) the correct approach but an argument is missing when the matrix is not diagonalizable in R.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Write

$z=x+iy$

and use Euler Formula $e^{iw}=\cos w+i\sin w$

and equate the real & the imaginary parts

Comment: Thanks, i´ve got that, if $z=x+iy \implies x=A \cos{t}+B\cos{t}$ and $y=A\sin{t}-B\sin{t}$, how can i continue?

Comment: Sorry but this is, at the most, an extremely preliminary hint.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}Z&=Ae^{it}+Be^{-it}\\
&=A(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))+B(\cos(t)-i\sin(t))\\
&=(A+B)\cos(t)+i(A-B)\sin(t)\\&=x+iy\\
\implies
x&=(A+B)\cos(t)\\
y&=(A-B)\sin(t)\end{align}

Comment: Jajaja, use Latex please

Comment: This approach fails when $A$ or $B$ is not real. (But this post got upvoted and, even, accepted while another answer tackles correctly the exercise... No comment.)